# How to get a read stream from a get request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Im using **yazl** to create a zip file with Node.js. You can add read stream to it. Im trying add photos that Im retrieving from a get request to the zip file. I have tried all the following but when I open the zip there's no photos inside.

Method 1:

```
  this.s3.getObject(params, (err, photos) => {
    photos = JSON.parse(photos.Body.toString());
    photos.forEach((photoUrl, i) => {
      let fileName = `${jobId}/getPhotoFile${i + 1}.jpg`;
      http.get(photoUrl, (response) => {
        zip.addReadStream(response, fileName);
      }).end();
    })
```

Method 2:

```
  this.s3.getObject( params, (err, photos) => {
    photos = JSON.parse(photos.Body.toString());
    photos.forEach((photoUrl, i) => {
      let fileName = `${jobId}/getPhotoFile${i + 1}.jpg`;
      zip.addReadStream(http.get(photoUrl), fileName);
    });
  });
```

Method 3:

```
  this.s3.getObject(params, (err, photos) => {
    photos = JSON.parse(photos.Body.toString());
    photos.forEach((photoUrl, i) => {
      let fileName = `${jobId}/getPhotoFile${i + 1}.jpg`;
      zip.addReadStream(request.get(photoUrl), fileName);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Where is `jobId` defined? Also, have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Its an argument to an outer function, its definitely defined properly though I debuged with logging